# How to show xticks in vertical fashion in matplotlib python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

How do you have category names as the xlabel without it all squeezing together? Below is my dictionary. I actually have my keys and values mixed up due to sorting, but the code is fine.

```
2 : theatre
16 : silent
234 : western
1230 : mystery
1296 : animated
1496 : fantasy
1584 : science
1922 : adventure
2176 : family
2767 : horror
4122 : action
4281 : romance
4804 : thriller
7105 : comedy
11147 : drama

keys, values = df_decades_obs_dict.values(), df_decades_obs_dict.keys()
plt.bar(range(len(values)), values, color='g')
plt.xticks(range(len(values)), keys)
plt.show()
```

Here is a photo of what the graph looks like:

[image]

Comment: use `plt.xticks(range(len(values)), keys,rotation=90)`

Comment: @venky__ make it an answer and i'll upvote you

Comment: You should mark the answer as "accepted"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `plt.xticks(range(len(values)), keys,rotation=90)` to rotate. more info in [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)